# Web Config Redirect to non-www

Tags: web-config

I have an azure hosted website where I need to enforce a few URL rules. 1) All requests must use HTTPS and 2) Remove the www from the beginning of the URL.

So the desired outcome is this:

```
http://example.com -> https://example.com
http://www.example.com -> https://example.com
https://www.example.com -> https://example.com
```

What I have below works when redirecting all urls to https but it does not handle redirecting to the non-www url.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear/>
    <rule name="Redirect from www" stopProcessing="false">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true"/>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" negate="false"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I have also tried the following but I get an error saying that the website redirected too many times.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear/>
    <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)"/>
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true"/>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" negate="false"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
<rules>
  <rule name="non-www" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/{R:1}" />
  </rule>
</rules>
```